# reactPlayer cant play local dash(mpd) file it return 403 status code (forbiden error)

Tags: reactjs, react-player

### my code is here

```
<ReactPlayer 
ref={playerRef}
className="video-Play"
width='100%'
height='100%'
url="../../assets/dash/2c65a6d0-10c9-4f7d-b053-373f4433faf4.mpd"
pip={pip} 
playing={playing}
/>
```

but when i use online mpd file link sample it works  forexample http://livesim.dashif.org/livesim/testpic_2s/two_regions.mpd

Comment: Do you have access to `../../assets/dash/2c65a6d0-10c9-4f7d-b053-373f4433faf4.mpd`?

Comment: yes @j3st it's a local disk of my computer